# How to set a property in class via Managed Bean?

Tags: java, xpages

I would like to set a property in my java class via the faces-config file:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>utilsBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.acme.bank.app.UtilsBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>filePath</property-name>
      <value>#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(@LeftBack(database.getFilePath(),"\\"),"\\","/")+"/"}</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
```

On my UtilsBean class I have as property:

```
public String filePath;
```

and

```
public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
```

But when I output the value in the constructor I get a null value.

```
public UtilsBean() throws Exception {
        super();        
        Database database = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        System.out.println("database.getFilePath() = " + database.getFilePath());//returns filepath of current nsf
        System.out.println("this filepath = " + this.filePath);//returns null


        try {
        ...
    }
}
```

To me it looks the property is not set via the faces-config or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Malin, an other approach is to set the value of filePath in your constructor, or read it whenever getFilePath() is called (and then remove setFilePath).

Comment: Hello Per, I was setting the filepath in the constructor by reading a value from a properties file. However I want the value to be computed. I thought the faces-config file was the "highest" level I could define it? and via a managed bean I would like to have the value accessible via ssjs and other java classes.

Comment: Hi Malin, but since the value is computed anyway you can just compute it either in the constructor or in the getter

Comment: Yes I see that, but I want to test the managed bean approach :-)

Comment: The constructor can't use the property as it is "too early". Try to use the properties later. I think that the managed properties values will be assigned to **instantiated** object. This is *after* constructor run.

Comment: Personally, I would stay away from managed properties. I don't think changing settings in the application's design is a good idea. I mostly create a config document in the application and read values from that in (for instance) that class you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Over my progression through Java in XPages, I've come to the conclusion that lazy-loading is better. It's also one of the big advantages over SSJS because it's much easier in Java. So something like:

`private String filePath;
public void getFilePath() {
  if (null == filePath) {
    setFilePath();
  }
  return filePath;
}
public void setFilePath() {
  filePath = getFilePathVariableInSomeWay();
}`

This means you're calling the setting code once, only when it's used and not when the object is instantiated.

It also avoids calling SSJS, which is not as performant. It also means you can debug the setting code. It also means you're using a language-specific editor, with associated compiling validation, for generating the setting code. XML can't validate SSJS. A Java editor can ensure you don't have any compile-time errors.

I'm not sure of the benefits of using the faces-config for computing managed bean properties, to be honest I've never used them. But I can see some strong advantages of using methods in the Java class itself, whether in the constructor or the getter.